# Prove that there exists an upper triangular matrix $U$ such that $U^TU=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a positive definite matrix \begin{pmatrix}
 a & b  \\
b & c  \\
\end{pmatrix}

prove that there exists an upper triangular matrix $U$ such that $U$ transpose times $U$ equals $A.$

I'm thinking that since the transpose of a matrix times itself is identity matrix, which is also in the form of A, will that be a solution?

Comment: Why do you say "since the transpose of a matrix times itself is identity matrix"?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I meant for a matrix A, (A^T)*A=I

Comment: This is not true in general. Consider $\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2  \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Then what should I do with this problem, I can't think of any other ways.

Comment: The basic way is to write $U=\begin{pmatrix}
 x & y  \\
0 & z  \\
\end{pmatrix}$, compute $U^T U$ and identify what should be the coefficients $x, y, z$ knowing that $U^T U = A$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net But I need to prove that UTU=A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U=\begin{pmatrix}u&v\\0&w\end{pmatrix}$. Then
$$UU^T=\begin{pmatrix}u&v\\0&w\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u&0\\v&w\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u^2+v^2&vw\\vw&w^2\end{pmatrix}$$

We see that 
$$w=\sqrt c$$ $$v=\frac b{\sqrt c}$$ $$u=\sqrt{a-\frac{b^2}c}$$

We should also show that all those radicands are nonnegative, but, applying the Sylvester's criterion:
$$ac-b^2\ge 0$$
and
$$a\ge 0$$
and therefore, $ac\ge 0$ and $c\ge 0$. Also, $a-(b^2/c)=(ac-b^2)/c\ge 0$.

Comment: Wasn't the question about $U^TU$?

Comment: @egreg i think 0.P look same as $UU^T$